# Not able to plot using plotly in python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have following Python dataframe and I want to plot Sno. vs each column values using plotly .

```
    TT  AN  AP  AR  AS  BR  CH  CT  DN  DL  ... PY  PB  RJ  SK  TN  TG  TR  UP  UT  WB
Sno.                                                                                    
1   81  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   ... 0   1   3   0   1   1   0   12  0   0
2   27  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   0   0   2   0   1   0   0
3   15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
4   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2   0   1
5   37  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   ... 0   1   3   0   1   8   0   2   1   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
147 rows × 36 columns
```

So here is my approach :

```
def plot_case(df):
    for i in df.columns.values :
        dn = df.index.values
        dc = df[i].values
        xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(title="Day number")
        yaxis = go.layout.YAxis(title="New cases")

        fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(title=i, xaxis=xaxis, yaxis=yaxis))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dn, y=dc))
```

```
plot_case(df)
```

But I am not getting any output in jupyter notebook, that cell just runs without giving any errors .

So I tried this approach for single column  **TT**

```
xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(title="Day number")
yaxis = go.layout.YAxis(title="New cases")

fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(title="TT", xaxis=xaxis, yaxis=yaxis))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index.values, y=df.TT.values))
```

And it worked !
So can someone please explain me what's wrong in that for loop ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more issues here, but you will in any case need to call

```
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

The root of the problem is the behavior of jupyter notebooks and how they determine cell output. Say you have a pandas DataFrame called `df`. If you now create a cell saying:

```py
df
```

you will receive the DataFrame as output to that cell upon execution. However, if you change the cell to

```py
new_df = df
```

or

```py
for i in range(5):
    df
```

you will no longer receive any output. The reason is for that is, that jupyter notebooks always output the last received output by default. The assignment of `new_df = df` doesn't return anything. Neither does the for loop. In order to see what you expect, you should use [vestland's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318309/5299750) and add `fig.show()` or `matplotplib.pyplot.plot()` to your for loop. That way you don't rely on the default output behavior of jupyter notebooks, but are guaranteed some output.

In the end, your code becomes:

```py
def plot_case(df):
    for i in df.columns.values :
        dn = df.index.values
        dc = df[i].values
        xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(title="Day number")
        yaxis = go.layout.YAxis(title="New cases")

        fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(title=i, xaxis=xaxis, yaxis=yaxis))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dn, y=dc))
        fig.show()
```

if you want individual plots, or

```py
def plot_case(df):
    xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(title="Day number")
    yaxis = go.layout.YAxis(title="New cases")
    fig = go.Figure(layout=go.Layout(title='comparison', xaxis=xaxis, yaxis=yaxis))
    dn = df.index.values
    for i in df.columns.values :
        dc = df[i].values
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dn, y=dc))
    fig.show()
```

If you want to have a comparison in just one plot, instead. Note that I pulled those lines out of the for loop that do not depend on your iterated values for efficiency.